# Parse (Push Notification) won't work in one of my apps

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am not sure why but Parse (Push Notification) won't work in my app but it works in all the other apps. I have checked many times and everything is exactly the same as the other apps. I have tried following many tutorials but it's unclear. My apps are signed and published. The other apps can send the notifications following the same way as below but one of my apps "Gurbani Ujagar" the following one doesn't send any notifications. Any help please?

I have the library imported.

ParseApplication.java

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "aaabbbbcccc", "bbbbbcccccdddd");


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

}

  }
```

MainPage.java

```
  public class MainPage extends SlidingActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainPage.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();


    getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    //getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.header);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);
             ....
```

Manifest File (I have all the permissions needed).

```
    android:name="ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="gurbani.ujagar.MainPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   .....
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainPage.class);` in the Application class. Also, check if the PushService for your app is running in the Android phone settings -> Apps Manager-> Running tasks